# is statsmodels' MLEModel class using Expectation Maximization for fitting?

Tags: python, statsmodels, expectation-maximization

I am building a custom stat space model using `statsmodels`' `MLEModel` class, and fitting the unknown parameters with the `.fit()` method. I thought that it was using Expectation Maximization, but I am not sure of that and I cannot find any hint to this in the documentation. Moreover, the verbose output of the `.fit()` method shows the steps of a single optimization, and this makes me even more doubtful.

If it is not using EM, what is it doing? maybe I am missing something here, but I thought that for models with hidden variables (like state space models) you cannot directly minimize the likelihood (since you don't know and don't observe the hidden states).

thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `MLEModel` uses a quasi-Newton approach to numerically find parameters that maximize the likelihood function. Ultimately, it relies on the [Scipy `minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function. The default algorithm is the [BFGS algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm), but you can select others using the `method` argument. For example, `method='nm'` uses the [Nelder-Mead algorithm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html#optimize-minimize-neldermead).

The Statsmodels state space framework provides all the tools (e.g. the appropriate smoothers) to use the EM algorithm, but you would have to implement it yourself. For example, the EM algorithm is the default method used to fit the [`DynamicFactorMQ`](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.dynamic_factor_mq.DynamicFactorMQ.html) model, because it has a large number of parameters, and quasi-Newton methods can be slow and unreliable for such problems.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `fit()` is a method of the model class. Depending on the class object the method fit() from that class will be called. In general, fit() estimates parameters `via maximum likelihood` and return a results object.

The `expectation maximization (EM)` algorithm requires and uses the `Kalman smoother` for models with hidden variables if I'm not mistaken.

EDIT: fit() will cal the fit() of its parent class which in this case is `tsbase.TimeSeriesModel` as seen in `class MLEModel(tsbase.TimeSeriesModel)`. In turn, `class TimeSeriesModel(base.LikelihoodModel)` will call its parent class which is `base.LikelihoodModel`. `class LikelihoodModel(Model)'s fit() function` default method argument is `'newton'`. Thus, **Maximum likelihood (ML) estimation will be estimated using Newton's method in this custom state space model.**

Comment: thank you @azal, but the point is precisely that i don't know whether the `fit` method of the class `MLEModel` is using the kalman smoother to estimate the hidden variable and then minimize the likelihood and repeat this n times, or it is not. I have created a custom class on the basis of `MLEModel` and I would like to know how it is estimating the parameters

Comment: This is what is does from what I understand. Uses kalman smoother for the estimation, minimizes likelihood and then repeats it.

Comment: but I don't see anywhere in the code the EM iteration, it's seems there is just a single optimization and no cycle of optimizations

Comment: can you send the link you're checking please?

Comment: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.html#MLEModel this is the source code of MLEModel, but here the `fit` method calls the fit method of its parent class, thus you need to go inside the library if you want to see what's happening

Comment: see my edit. I hope it answers your query.